# Python code exits with error while reading input

Tags: python, algorithm, input

I was trying [this coding contest](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/TECHELN4/), and my simple brute force python code fails with a "Non-Zero Exit Code".  I think the issue may be with reading empty lines. Could someone please give me a tip??

```
import sys
n = int(raw_input())
sys.stdin.readline()
a=map(int,raw_input().split())
sys.stdin.readline()
t = int(raw_input())
sys.stdin.readline()
for i in range(1, t+1):
k = int(raw_input())
if k*k in a:
    print "YES"
else:
    print "NO"
```

Comment: The example input on that page is not consistent with the description of the input format.

Comment: Be careful using Python for that problem. Unless I'm very much mistaken, the expected output assumes 32-bit integer overflow.

Comment: @DanielFischer, while on the topic..is there a classier way to do this problem??

Comment: Not really. Depending on the data, it may be faster or slower to filter out obvious non-squares first, but basically there's nothing else but putting the 'random' numbers in a set and looking up the squares in that set. By the way, the problem is now hidden, presumably due to incorrect test data, so when it is unhidden, overflow will probably no more be expected.

Comment: @DanielFischer. if the test data was wrong...how did all those ppl get accepted solutions???

Comment: Probably the same way I did. Using a 32-bit type that overflows.

Answer (score 0):

*First line consists of N, the count of the random numbers.*

You've got this one fine.

*Next N lines consist of these N numbers.*

This seems to imply one number per line, I'd do something like this:

```
numbers = []
for i in range(n):
    numbers += int(sys.stdin.readline())
```

The T looks okay.

Comment: Hmm.. Test data for that problem was deemed incorrect . Its been hidden. Thanks angusiguess and Daniel Fischer anyway.